# How do I create an array of partial objects from another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects, and I want to copy the array, but not include all the properties of the objects in the new array. Is there a better way to do that than this?

```
let objects = [{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:4,b:5,c:6},{a:7,b:8,c:9}]

let partialObjects = objects.map(object => {
    let { a, ...partial } = object;
    return partial;
});
```

Desired Output:

```
[{b:2, c:3},{b:5, c:6},{b: 8, c:9}]
```

Comment: you can do as: let partials = objects.map(({b, c}) => ({b,c}) );

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use destructuring directly in the arrow function in case you want more concise syntax:

```js
let objects = [{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:4,b:5,c:6},{a:7,b:8,c:9}]

let partialObjects = objects.map(({a,...rest})=> rest);
console.log(partialObjects);
```